# Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException in the equalizer

Tags: android, exception, equalizer

I am trying to fix a bug in my app but the problem is I am not able to fix the bug
as i am not able to recreate the crash but I am able to get the log and i am not able to identify what is the issue i referred the question related to **UnsupportedOperationException** but till now no success any guide of hint will be helpful

Log1

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to create service com.musicplayer.music.audioplayer.PlayerService: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: AudioEffect: set/get parameter error
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:2801)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800 (ActivityThread.java:155)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1400)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5343)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:905)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

logcat 2

```
    Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
 AudioEffect: set/get parameter error
android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.<init> (AudioEffect.java:407)
android.media.audiofx.Virtualizer.<init> (Virtualizer.java:120)
com.musicplayer.music.audioplayer.equalizermerge.model.EqualizerApi.init 
(EqualizerApi.java:23)
com.musicplayer.music.audioplayer.PlayerService.onCreate 
(PlayerService.java:400)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:3141)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800 (ActivityThread.java:178)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1640)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6102)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

As suggested i have added the complete log cat from the **io.fabric** [EqualizerApi code](https://github.com/neelayak/Equalizer-Api/tree/master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a version of the source code (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5bb8f80/media/java/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.java), though the line numbers don't match your stacktrace.

It appears that an `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown as a result of a problem when initializing the native code implementation of the audio effect engine.  In the code I am looking at, the exception message says "Effect library not loaded".  I am guessing it is caused  by one of the following:

- A required native library is missing from the load path.  (Maybe you haven't included it in the app ...)
- It is possible that there is a bug in the library's initialization code.

---

**Update** - The updated stacktrace and error message indicate that the problem is happening when you create the `Virtualizer`.  The message implies that it is due to a bad parameter.

Looking through the code for the AudioEffect and Virtualizer classes, it appears that the `Virtualizer` initialzer is attempting to retrieve a parameter from the native API to test if the Virtualizer "strength" parameter is supported.  It appears like the API is saying that it doesn't even understand the parameter that is supposed to say whether the strength parameter is supported(!)

The comments in the Virtualizer class near where the parameter numbers are specified say this:

```
// These constants must be synchronized with those in 
// frameworks/base/include/media/EffectVirtualizerApi.h
```

Based on the behavior I deduced, it seems that is not true.  In other words, I think ... somehow ... you are using a version of the Java API that doesn't match the version of the native API.

Alternatively, this might be happening because Virtualizer support is broken on those devices.

I would suggest the following work-arounds:

1. Try to catch the runtime exception in your `init` method, and treat the Virtualizer functionality as disabled on the device.
2. If you know what the offending devices are, code your `init` method to not even try to configure a Virtualizer on those devices.
3. Don't support those devices at all.  (Are they old?  Are they running old / poorly maintained builds of Android?  Are they even *worth* supporting?)

It is also possible that the problem is related one of these Q&As:

- [Using audioSessionId value to instantiate AudioFx class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193239/using-audiosessionid-value-to-instantiate-audiofx-class)
- [UnsupportedOperationException AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323140/unsupportedoperationexception-audioeffect-invalid-parameter-operation)

Comment: Sir the following code is running properly in my device but in some users it is throwing this exception

Comment: Unless you can provide more information (e.g. the relevant parts of **your** source code) I can't investigate further.   You could start by providing us a complete stacktrace, with the complete exception message.

Comment: Alternatively, if `com.musicplayer.music.audioplayer.equalizermerge.model.EqualizerApi` is a 3rd-party API, contact the vendor for support.

Comment: No sir its my app and the following bug is happening in my equalizer

Comment: Sir i have added as you said, I can't post the complete code as the site don't allow me so i put the code of equalizerApi in Github

Comment: Sir the app run properly in most of the device but it crashes in some of the devices like Motorola, TLC, Blu  also there is a chance its a bug as it happen in specific mobile

Comment: I have updated the code sir I will update the answer as i update the app

Comment: I found the similar issue I guess by putting this case in catch will use the default value of mediasession